# How to write a simple WP7 unit test using xUnitContrib?

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7, resharper, xunit.net

I'm working from the [XunitContrib codeplex page](http://xunitcontrib.codeplex.com/releases/view/62697) and toward the bottom it lists these steps

For Windows Phone 7
Follow along with [this](http://www.smartypantscoding.com/a-cheat-sheet-for-unit-testing-silverlight-apps-on-windows-phone-7) blog post
Create a Windows Phone application
Add references to:

- Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.dll (Silverlight 3 version - included in release)
- xunit-silverlight-wp7
- xunit.extensions-silverlight-wp7
- xunitcontrib.runner.silverlight.toolkit-wp7

Visual Studio may display warnings about including Silverlight 3 assemblies. Ignore it, these are the right files

Add [Fact] based tests and run the app (note- the blog post mentioned isn't using fact based tests so I'm even more confused ...)

But after I add the above mentioned dll's and start with something like the below ... resharper and I can't seem to hookup the testing harness enough to compile. Has anyone actually wired up a unit test with xunit for WP7?

```
public class MyFirstWp7Test
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Can_Run_Test_For_WP7()
        {
           var x = "hello world";

           Assert.Equal("hello world", x);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to test-drive my app on the WP7 platform using NUnit and ReSharper.

I did a short screencast on my blog for a full "how-to" of sorts

http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2011/07/24/Test-Driving-My-Windows-Phone-7-App

Answer (score 1):

You can't use resharper to run Silverlight or Windows Phone tests, unfortunately. The xunitcontrib resharper runner is for the desktop clr only (newer builds ignore files in a silverlight/wp project so you don't even see the unit test marker in the editor).

You need to actually deploy to the device or emulator, run your application and drive the tests through the UI of the Silverlight Unit Testing Framework. You can filter by tag, test class or test method name, but it all has to be in the phone's environment.

Comment: So it's not possible to run this against a simple class like nUnit or jUnit? Does any option exist that does for wp7? I'm really not interested in deploying these tests to the device or simulator just to assert something. The feedback is much too slow with this framework (sorry)